# gcloud crash while requesting a build (Google Container Builder) from Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: gcloud, google-container-registry, bitbucket-pipelines

We use bitbucket for git repo hosting and started using pipelines for the testing, but now I'm looking at the next step, deployment.

I want to make use of Google Container Builder and trigger this from pipelines. There is a `Dockerfile` located at `kubernetes/nginx/` which should be sent to Google Container Builder.

When I run the following command locally it works perfect:

```
gcloud container builds submit --tag gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/website/nginx kubernetes/nginx/
```

But as part of the pipeline I get the following error:

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

gcloud version:

```
Google Cloud SDK 143.0.1
bq 2.0.24
bq-nix 2.0.24
core 2017.02.09
core-nix 2017.02.09
gcloud 
gcloud-deps 2017.02.09
gcloud-deps-linux-x86_64 
gsutil 4.22
gsutil-nix 4.22
kubectl 
kubectl-linux-x86_64 1.5.2
```

Things i've checked:

- I'm authenticated properly so that isn't the problem.
- I also verified that the files needed for the build are accessible.

Comment: Do you happen to have a .dockerignore file?

Comment: yes I do @JasonHall, but that wasn't a problem :)

Comment: We found the bug, and it will be fixed in the next gcloud release. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added the following commands before the build request:

```
gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west1-d
gcloud config set project *Project id here*
```

After adding this it worked, so I think the problem was not having access to the zone or project data.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a correct workaround. The core issue is a bug in the source, which I will now fix.

Comment: Came here by searching for the same error message.
I wanted to list my container images in a CI pipeline using the command `gcloud container images list-tags ...` and got the same error. 
The suggested two config settings here didn't solve my issue, but running `gcloud projects list` command just before the list-tags did. Weird :)

I was using the google/cloud-sdk:apline docker image:
<pre>
gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 224.0.0
bq 2.0.36
core 2018.11.02
gsutil 4.34
</pre>